# In the male quarters, how exactly does the male crew of the Thousand Sunny sleep?

Tags: one-piece

This question is regarding **One Piece**.

As I was going through the design of the **Thousand Sunny** on Wikia, I came across [**this**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Thousand_Sunny?file=Thousand_sunny_boys_room.png) image of **The boys' room**, which I've posted below:

[image]

As can be seen here, there are six hammocks in the image, verified by [**this**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Thousand_Sunny#Men.27s_and_Women.27s_Quarters) link.

> Suspended from the ceiling like wooden hammocks are **three
>   double-decker bunks**, which the men sleep in.

It also adds that

> Behind these bunks, at
>   the back of the room, are **six** lockers where the men can store their
>   clothes.

Since there are seven male members in the Straw Hat crew, there must be one person who doesn't get to sleep in a hammock and who doesn't have a locker. My question is, who is it?

I came across [**this**](http://www.narutoforums.com/showthread.php?t=810848) and [**this**](http://feriowind.deviantart.com/art/OP-Daily-life-on-Sunny-1-132802881) link which pose a similar question.
The answers which seem to be valid are

- Sanji sleeping in the kitchen

I don't think Sanji sleeps in the kitchen, but there is a couch to the right [**here**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Thousand_Sunny?file=Thousand_sunny_kitchen.png), does Sanji sleep there?

I think Sanji does have a locker to himself.

- Zoro sleeping in the crow's nest

The [**crow's nest**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Thousand_Sunny?file=Thousand_sunny_crows_nest.png) seems to have wooden benches, but I doubt Zoro sleeps there.

I think Zoro has a locker to himself, too.

- Brook not sleeping

In an SBS question, Oda has said that Brook sleeps for five hours. [**This**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Straw_Hat_Pirates/Miscellaneous#Typical_Hours_of_Sleep) is the link. [**This**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_74#Chapter_737.2C_Page_126) link gives their sleep timings. So that eliminates the possibility that Brook doesn't sleep. Maybe he doesn't sleep in this room though?

I can't guess if he has a locker or not.

- Chopper sleeping on the bed in the Sick Bay

This seems like the most plausible solution, since Chopper considers the [**Sick Bay**](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Thousand_Sunny?file=Thousand_sunny_sick_bay.png#Kitchen.2C_Dining_Room.2C_and_Sick_Bay) as his personal room, provided the bed isn't reserved for patients.

He might be the one who doesn't have a locker, since he can keep his stuff in the infirmary.

- One of them is on night watch, so there are enough hammocks for the rest

This is possible, but is it true? If it is, was there any rare occasion when none of them was on watch? I highly doubt it, but if the answer is yes, how did they sleep then?

Even if they did manage to sleep somehow (one of them on the floor, for example), there are still six lockers though, so who doesn't have a locker to himself?

The following image provides a pretty nice solution, but this is an image from when the Straw Hats were on the *Going Merry*. Do they use the same solution on the *Thousand Sunny* too?

[image]

A person who has seen the anime or read the manga, or done both, might probably know the answer. Any help is highly appreciated.

---

I apologize for the lengthy question. I haven't watched or read One Piece. I came across it about a month ago and it drew my attention greatly. My knowledge is mostly limited to the information I gained by reading the Wikipedia and Wikia pages of One Piece.

Comment: well we can assume that they sleep like they did on Going Merry, they're luffy's crew after all, the only one who sleep in normal position is the girls

Comment: Yes, we can always assume, but I was hoping for some solid facts. If anyone can say with certainty that there's no information about this, then I'll give up. And do you have any idea regarding the locker?

Comment: also, when Thousand Sunny was built, Brook haven't join Luffy's crew, Franky probably add one more hammock and locker after that, but I don't remember it ever mention anywhere, it only an extra page after all

Comment: That is possible. Thanks! Is there any mention about where Franky sleeps?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, there are six hammocks and six male members before Brook join, the number match

Comment: @ Oshino Shinobu Sorry, I hadn't given attention to the "one more hammock" part of your comment.

Comment: @Peter Raeves Thank you! An extra bed might be the answer to this. I was thinking there might have been a scene in the manga or anime when they are sleeping, but I guess I'm out of luck. By the way, do you mean, 1 person is awake? I haven't said anything about 2 people being awake.

Comment: @Matte It was in the [link to the SBS](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_74#Chapter_737.2C_Page_126). Oda mentioned that there should always be two people awake at the same time. One checking the front of the ship and another checking the back of the ship.

Comment: @Peter Raeves Thank you for that piece of info! I'd only glanced at the sleep times and had ignored the rest.

Comment: I tried putting all things we know into an answer. I hope it didn't turn out too long.

Comment: Has anyone considered that the ship has someone up at all times meaning a look out so there may be a two people that share a bed just at different points of the day.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**TL;DR:** If a 7th bed was needed Franky would have build one, but it doesn't seem like any of them should sleep on the floor against their will even if they only had 6.

To begin with, the pictures you showed were after Franky had joined. So whether he built a pirate ship for 5 male crew members and added a bed for himself after he joined or he put it there from the beginning considering a new crew member might join, **Franky would easily be able to just build a 7th bed if needed**. Heck, he could build a pretty sturdy bridge just on the spot in Thriller Bark.

Additionally, Oda confirmed that there should always be two crew members awake at all time. In the [SBS of Volume 74, Chapter 737](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_74#Chapter_737.2C_Page_126), Oda mentioned the Strawhats' daily schedule. He also said that **at all times there should be two crew members awake**. One should guard the front of the ship and another should guard the back of the ship.

> D: I would like to know the Straw Hats' bed times and wake up times! - Penname fujiyama
>
> O: I see. A very interesting question indeed. These people don't really follow much of a schedule but. In general.
>
> And thus, even during instances where they have to navigate through the seas during nighttime, there will always need to be **at least two people awake at all times** in order to keep an eye out in both the front and back directions of the ship, hence every member alternates every 2 hours to stay on the lookout. It isn't too uncommon that these people don't get sufficient sleep.

[image]
[image]

On top of that, from chapter 699 it looks like they have enough beds as it is. Chapter 699 is the only chapter I could find where you could actually see the Stawhats asleep. At that time Sanji and Kinemon couldn't sleep jealous of Momonosuke and Usopp and Chopper couldn't sleep afraid of Doflamingo. Despite the fact that most of them were empty, you can see **Luffy and Brook share a bed**. Finally you can see Law and Caesar sleep outside. We can also see Franky sleepy, but outside guarding the ship as Oda mentioned. So whether Brook and Luffy always share a bed or it was just a coincidence, it looks like due to their random way of sleeping and with beds and couches all over the place, **they don't even need al 6 beds to begin with**.

Finally seeing Zoro sleep in a bed, **it is safe to assume like you said that they all sleep in their beds as much as possible**. Sanji does not sleep in the kitchen, Zoro does not sleep in the crow's nest, Chopper does not sleep in the infirmary bed, which is supposed to remain clean and sterile, and Brook does indeed sleep. Despite them sleeping in their beds mostly, they still don't need all 6 as mentioned earlier where Luffy sleeps in random places most likely and two need to be awake to guard the ship anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Brook was the newest official member of the strawhat crew and therefore the Sunny was not modified yet to showcase his own personal space.

This is mostly in part to the 2Y timeskip that occurred when the crew got back together there hasn't been a real revamp of the Sunny. The crew just bought stuff with them and added it to the ship.

So the person who doesn't have a space is Brook.

Comment: Well, Franky build a 6th hammock when he entered the crew, so why do you think he didn't build a 7th when Brook joined? Do you have any proof that Brook doesn't have space?

Comment: Thank you :) Franky would have built a seventh bed for Brook, if necessary, it just wasn't shown to the readers perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a working ship, so the crew will be split into watches, e.g. First/morn, afternoon/middle, last dog.

This means that at all times a portion of the crew is awake and on duty, so unless the crew drastically increases in size, six bunks for the men is more than adequate.

Comment: This is already explained in detail with official source on [the accepted answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/26520/2516). If you could provide better information, feel free to [edit] and improve your answer.